# Recursively explore a multidimensional vector

Tags: rust

I am currently learning Rust. I am trying to convert a small project written in a dynamic language as I learn. I have come across a problem which I am struggling find a solution for.

I wish to recursively visit each element of a vector of *n* dimensions.

The following is generalised code of the problem:

```
explore(collection) {
    for item in collection {
        if item is Collection {
            explore(item)
        }
        else {
            operate(item)
        }
    }
}
```

I am using `rustc 1.0.0 (a59de37e9 2015-05-13) (built 2015-05-14)`

It sort of feels like this isn't possible without resorting to using unsafe code (which I have yet to learn).

My questions are as follows:

1. Is this currently possible in Rust?
2. If so, then what would be the most Rust-like approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  There are a few ways you could potentially do it, but without more details, I'm just going to suggest the following, relatively simple approach:

```rust
// In Rust, prefer to use an enum over dynamic dispatch.
enum Item<T> {
    Collection(Vec<Item<T>>),
    Value(T),
}

// This explore function is generic over both the type being stored (T),
// and the operation to be performed on values.
fn explore<T, F>(collection: &[Item<T>], operate: &mut F)
where F: FnMut(&T) {
    for item in collection {
        match item {
            &Item::Collection(ref items) => explore(items, operate),
            &Item::Value(ref value) => operate(value)
        }
    }
}

fn operate_i32(value: &i32) {
    println!("operate({})", value);
}

fn main() {
    use Item::*;

    let root = vec![
        Value(1),
        Collection(vec![
            Value(2),
            Value(3),
        ]),
        Value(4),
    ];

    explore(&root, &mut operate_i32)
}
```

Further pertinent reading can be found in the Rust Book chapters on [Enums](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/enums.html), [the `match` construct](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/match.html) and [closures](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/closures.html).

Comment: What is the upside of using a `&mut F` / `FnMut` compared to the simpler naive `&F` / `Fn` ?

Comment: `F: FnMut` is *more broadly useful*.  Look at it like this: there is no particular reason to *not* allow closures that mutate their environment, so we might as well allow them.  `F: Fn` is not really any simpler, either, just *different*.  A different trait, and it only requires an immutable pointer rather than a mutable one.  The semantics of the `explore` function are simple enough that the pointer being mutable isn't even inconvenient.  `/shrug`

Comment: Can we have several calls of `&mut operate_i32` ? Shouldn't that lock the function for other calls ? But i see your point. Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to avoid the enum wrappers if I knew that the vectors were homogeneous, and the only unknown was the number of dimensions? eg `Vec<Vec<T>>` or `Vec<Vec<Vec<T>>>`

Comment: @tafia: In this case, no.  There's nothing to *persist* the borrow beyond the call to `explore`.  We take a borrow, pass it to `explore`, and then it goes away.

Comment: @Dale: That sounds like a different question.  In *that* case, you're dealing with progressively deconstructing a type.  Short answer: you'd want a trait that both `Vec<X>` and `T` implement with a method that somehow abstracts the behaviour that differs between the two cases.  In other words: traits are how you do overloading in Rust.  If you need more than that, it might be best to ask a more specific question.

Comment: @DK: Thanks. It is a bit of a side question. I tried using traits to no avail. I might just leave it for now.